# NSCalendar initialisation unwrapping to nil, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi Iam try to initialise a NSCalendar object, however it keeps unwrapping to nil because I am forcing it to unwrap and because `Gregorian` obviously isn't a valid identifier. I can't seem to find any decent info and I have looked up Apple's documentation but I didn't get any further. It did say something about checking NSLocale, but I still couldn't figure it out.

Here is my code.

```
let calender: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: "Gregorian")!
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What you didn't find in [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Calendar_Keys) ? All available calendar types are specified there.

Comment: Thank you for that, yeah I obviously didn't click into the right thing. Now I can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `NSGregorianCalendar` identifier like this:

```
let calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
```

The full list of identifiers can be found in the 

[NSLocale Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSLocale_Calendar_Keys)

Comment: Got to wait those 10 minutes. Then I shall accept of course.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation `NSLocale`:

These constants identify NSCalendar instances

`NSString * const  NSGregorianCalendar;
NSString * const  NSBuddhistCalendar;
NSString * const  NSChineseCalendar;
NSString * const  NSHebrewCalendar;
NSString * const  NSIslamicCalendar;
NSString * const  NSIslamicCivilCalendar;
NSString * const  NSJapaneseCalendar;
NSString * const  NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar;
NSString * const  NSPersianCalendar;
NSString * const  NSIndianCalendar;
NSString * const  NSISO8601Calendar;`

Comment: Midhub MP has guided me to the correct link above for the documentation. Thank you though!